# Некорректно передаётся файл через сокет

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть код клиента:

```
Socket mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("123.456.789.0", 50), 10000);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
OutputStream out = mSocket.getOutputStream();
out.write("image number 3".getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile); // mFile - файл с картинкой
while (true) {
    byte[] i3 = new byte[65536];
    int i4 = mFileInputStream.read(i3, 0, 65536);
    if (i4 < 0) {
        mFileInputStream.close();
        break;
    } else {
        out.write(i3, 0, i4);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

И код сервера:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.in, "UTF-8"));
String i1 = in.readLine();
ByteArrayOutputStream i3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while (true) {
    try {
        byte[] i4 = new byte[1024];
        int i5 = this.in.read(i4, 0, 1024);
        if (i5 < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            i3.write(i4, 0, i5);
            i3.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        i3.close();
        break;
    }
}
BufferedImage mBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(i3.toByteArray()));
```

Примерно каждую 4-ю попытку отправить фотографию на сервер и считать её вылетает ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.lnproduction.ru.gks.server.I1$WebClient.run(I1.java:101)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Строка 101: `BufferedImage mBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(i3.toByteArray()));`. Попробовал использовать отладчик, и выяснилось, что отправляется 116К байтов, а приходит чуть меньше, например, примерно приблизительно 113К. Я вообще не понимаю как такое возможно. Может у меня где-то в коде ошибка? Дело в том, что в роли клиента выступает приложение на телефоне, а в роли сервера программа на компьютере. Помогите исправить. Я пол дня просидел над этой ошибкой, голова кругом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442168/wrong-sending-and-receiving-photos-through-socket).

Нельзя использовать `BufferedReader`, если отправлял не при помощи `BufferedWriter`, то бишь рекомендуется отправлять с помощью `DataOutputStream` и получать с `DataInputStream`.